# Actualizar versión jQuery en Genexus

Tags: c#, jquery, aplicación-web, genexus15

Cuando se despliega una versión generada con Genexus 15 si inspeccionamos el elemento en Google Chrome veremos que utiliza la versión 1.9.1 de jQuery, esto ocurre porque internamente el componente gxgral.js que viene por defecto utiliza dicha versión; en versiones actuales como Genexus 16 se mantiene la misma versión del componente.

Mis consultas son:

1. Por qué en las nuevas versiones de GeneXus se mantiene la versión 1.9.1 en sus componentes como gxgral.js
2. Es posible realizar una actualización del componente manualmente; hasta el momento he intentado actualizar el componente de la versión 1.9.1 a la versión 3.3.1 lo cual genera una serie de errores que impiden desplegar el sitio generado
3. De no ser posible actualizar el componente, cómo se puede comprobar que el uso de jQuery 1.9.1 no ocasiona vulnerabilidades en un sitio

Comment: cuales serian esos errores? el problema es que falla la actualizacion o si actualiza pero esa nueva version causa problemas en el codigo generado

Comment: el error es interno, se reemplazó la libreria jquery.js de 1.9.1 a la versión 3.3.1 y presentaron errores al desplegar la aplicación web, como el siguiente: e.indexOf is not a function.

Comment: se intentó corregir el error antes mencionado modificando la libreria gxgral.js pero eso me está llevando a más errores.